# How to not shink the white background field when no text or having only the white space

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I don't know that how to expand the span background color if there is on text inside like this.

[image: white background is shrunk when is no text inside the tag]

I want the white background with on text to remain the same size as white background with text.

My CSS

```
.dashboard-data-field {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  align-content: center;
}
.dashboard-data-header {
  padding: 4px;
}
.dashboard-data-description {
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

My JavaScript

```
                <div className="dashboard-data-field">
                    <span className="dashboard-data-header">ชื่อ-นามสกุล</span>
                    <span className="dashboard-data-description">{`${auth.user.firstname} ${auth.user.lastname}`}</span>
                </div>
```

Comment: give the element either a `min-height` or a fixed `height` that is equal or larger then the line-height incl. padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try two different solutions:

- Adding a `&nbsp;` as the content of the html element when it's
  supposed to be empty.
- Or you could add the css style attribute `min-height: 1em;` in the rules addressing header and description. *(I corrected this part compared to what I wrote before)*

I picked the second option here because consistent with css font-size arbitrarily chosen and doesn't require you to modify the logic to fill the contents adding a non blank space when it's empty:

```css
.dashboard-data-field {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  align-content: center;

  /*the field background is yellow to get contrast with the description bg*/
  background-color: yellow;
}
.dashboard-data-header {
  display: block;
  padding: 4px;

  /*this shows the size of the header*/
  border: solid 1px red;

  /*minimum height is 1em even when the content is empty*/
  min-height: 1em;
}
.dashboard-data-description {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;

  /*this background will cover the parent background*/
  background-color: #fff;

  /*this shows the size of the header*/
  border: solid 1px red;
  border-top: none;

  /*minimum height is 1em even when the content is empty*/
  min-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="dashboard-data-field">
  <span class="dashboard-data-header">Header with content</span>
  <span class="dashboard-data-description">Description with content</span>
</div>

<br>

<div class="dashboard-data-field">
  <span class="dashboard-data-header"></span>
  <span class="dashboard-data-description"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I like the `&nbsp` style that depending on text size but I'm afraid that fetching data with empty string will replace the span. Thank you.

Comment: I updated my answer since your last comment and I use the min-height set to 1em. It means its height will be the size of font-size for that element.

Answer (score 1):

Give fixed height to span from where you wanna show text

```
.dashboard-data-field {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: row;
    align-content: center;
  }
  .dashboard-data-header {
    padding: 4px;
  }
  .dashboard-data-description {
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: red;
    height: 40px;
  }
```

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="dashboard-data-field">
        <span className="dashboard-data-header">ชื่อ-นามสกุล</span>
        <span className="dashboard-data-description">with text</span>
      </div>
      <div className="dashboard-data-field">
        <span className="dashboard-data-header">ชื่อ-นามสกุล</span>
        <span className="dashboard-data-description"></span>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is an easier solution but it has a fix height, if I want to change `font-size` I must change `width` too.